# What is the difference between these two python3 versions?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two python3 versions. One is located in `/usr/local/bin/python3.7` and the other one in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Python may be installed in multiple locations on your computer. The default on your computer may be:
`/user/local/bin/python3.7`

You may also have another directory which in this case its: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3`

The first one is just a symlink of the second one.